# Is there any way you can interate through a list of method calls in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, collections

Say if I wanted to put those methods calls under the runnable (ahead(), turnLeft(), back() etc), into a collection list or array and one executes after other. Can this be done? This is robot game calledn "RobotCode", by the way.
Thanks in advance.

```java
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class NeuBot extends Robot
{

    int rapidFire = 2;
    //RobotHit rbHit = new RobotHit(null);
    public String name;
    boolean firing = false;
    int trigger;
    int turnDirection = 2;
    final int MOVES = 5;
    boolean wasHit = true;
    int moveOne = 1;
    int moveTwo = 2;
    int moveThree = 3;

    ArrayList<Integer> moveLst = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public void run()
    {

        while (true)
        {
            //Methods Defined within the Robot Class 
            ahead(100);
            back(200);
            turnLeft(180);
            turnRight(180);
            onScannedRobot(null);
            onHitRobot(null);
        }

    }

    //Robot Has Target
    public void onScannedRobot(ScannedRobotEvent e)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < MOVES; ++i)
        {
            firing = true;
            fire(rapidFire);
            if (firing == true)
            {
                back(50);
                out.println("Moved Back"); //TestX
            }
        }
        turnRight(10);
        ahead(20);

    }

    //
    public void onHitRobot(HitRobotEvent e)
    {
        out.println("Hit");
        wasHit = true;
        if (wasHit == true)
        {
            //Move Ahead And Fire
            ahead(20);
            fire(rapidFire);
            out.print("Fired Again!");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straightforward solution: use a list of `Runnable` like in:

```java
List<Runnable> commands = List.of(
    () -> ahead(100),
    () -> back(200),
    () -> turnLeft(180),
    () -> turnRight(180),
    () -> onScannedRobot(null),
    () -> onHitRobot(null)
);
```

above creates an unmodifiable list, but *usual* lists can also be used like in and commands added dynamically:

```java
List<Runnable> commands = new ArrayList<>():
commands.add( () -> ahead(100) );
commands.add( () -> back(200) );
// ...
```

These lists can be used in Java 8 Streams:

```java
commands.forEach(Runnable::run);
```

or in *usual* loops:

```java
for (Runnable command : commands) {
    command.run();
    // additional statements, e.g. Thread.sleep(...) for some delay
}
```

---

A more complex solution would be to create your own `Command` interface (or use `Runnable`) and implementing classes which would store the needed arguments.

Comment: Thanks! For your feedback! I'll give that a try.